# throwing new exceptions in catch()

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to catch an exception, add information to it, and throw a new (enhanced) exception for the calling module.

Example:

```
    void CallingMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            doStuff();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    void doStuff()
    {
        try
        {
            // do something here that may throw an error
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Exception e2 = new Exception("new added info", e);
            throw e2;
        }
        finally()
        {
            // cleanup
        }
    }
```

but when the error occurs and is written to the console, it is the original error not my new error containing the string "new added info".

Is this expected? How should I throw a ***new*** error to be caught?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this.. seems to be the new exception with the original one as the inner exception..

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, and "new info added" is the first thing output to the console.

Comment: What is original exception?

Comment: I've just found the problem - the "cleanup" in finally() was throwing another exception.
Once I rectify this I get the expected behaviour - my new e2 feeds through.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has already been answered by the OP.

Comment: @retailcoder: The actual code has been omitted by OP

Comment: @retailcoder: what was the point of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      DoSomething() ;
      return ;
    }
    static void DoSomething()
    {
      try
      {
        DoSomethingThatFails() ;
      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "This is the wrapper exception" , e ) ;
      }
    }
    static int DoSomethingThatFails()
    {
      int x = 3 ;
      int y = 0 ;
      int z = x / y ; // can you say "divide by zero"?
      return z ;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what gets written to the console:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This is the wrapper exception ---> System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at ConsoleApplication20.Program.DoSomethingThatFails() in ...\Program.cs:line 32
   at ConsoleApplication20.Program.DoSomething() in ...\Program.cs:line 21
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ConsoleApplication20.Program.DoSomething() in ...\Program.cs:line 25
   at ConsoleApplication20.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 14
```

You'll notice the first line consists of the outer exception and its message (`InvalidOperationException` and `This is the wrapper exception`), followed by an arrow (`--->`), followed by the inner exception (`DivideByZeroException` and `Attempted to divide by zero.`).

The next two lines are the stack trace of the **inner** exception, followed by a marker to indicate the end of the inner exception's stack trace. Then you get the stack trace for the **outer** exception.

All the information is there, you're just not seeing it.

Comment: my situation was actually not as you expected here (see my comment on the question - I had another error being thrown in finally()), but this answer could have been the cause, so I have accepted it, thanks